# How to find and change color of specific word in string

Tags: php

For example if I have

```
$data = "This is bold and this is italic";
// Guessing to read string with some inbuilt function and replace bold and italic keyword
```

I want to change the bold to **bold** and italic to *italic* in string.
Is this possible?

Comment: I want to change 'bold' to <b>tag then bold then close </b> Similarly <i>tag then italic then </i>

Comment: `str_replace("bold", "<b>bold</b>", $input)`?

Comment: `<b>` and `<i>` should not be used! Use `<strong>` and `<em>` instead (which have a *semantic* meaning instead of just formatting)

Comment: @ThiefMaster why would the literal words *"bold"* and *"italic"* require semantic markup in this context?  `<b>` and `<i>` are still perfectly acceptable within all of the *HTML* specifications.

Comment: I assume he'll use it for different things and this was just an example

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's an important distinction between the two but I don't think it's helpful to state that `<b>` and `<i>` simply should not be used.  If anything they are literally meaningless (harmless) - miss-use of `<strong>` and `<em>` is the greater sin and far more prevalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = str_replace(array('bold', 'italic'),
                    array('<span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span>',
                          '<span style="font-style: italic;">italic</span>'),
                    $data);
```

Instead of inline styles, you could instead specify classes like 'class="bold"` in the spans, and use CSS to assign the appropriate styles to those classes.

Comment: $data = " Registered:Jul 30, 2012 
       this is bold
       ";
       $data = str_replace('bold', '<span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span>', $data); Not working

Answer (score 1):

The data you return, assuming this isn't some form of `ajax` request, is going to be interpreted and rendered as `HTML`, so take advantage of that by including the tags in the output `string`.

**Example**

```
$data = "this is <strong>bold</strong> and this is <em>italic</em>";
```

And this will render something like..

This is **bold** and this is *italic*.

**Extra Reading**

- [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) is a nice explanation of semantic elements in HTML5.